# Pandas - Sum values in one column in between values in another

Tags: python, pandas

I want to sum the values in one column based on the values in another in Pandas. 
See figure below.

In one column(A) is a value of 1 or 0, and in column B another a value. Every time the value in the first column = 1 I need to add(sum) the values in the second column in between two ones.

In other words between two events (indicated by one), I need to add the total amount of other things (column b) that happened.

[image]

Comment: In the first example you include the value in row with the first "1", while in the second example you do not. You result should be either (12, 14) or (17, 18). Please correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for `sum`s and [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) for add empty strings or `NaN`s if need numeric column:

```
a = df['A'].shift().cumsum().fillna(df['A'].iat[0])
df['C'] = np.where(a.duplicated(keep='last'), '', df['B'].groupby(a).transform('sum')) 

print (df)
   A  B   C
0  1  5    
1  0  2    
2  0  1    
3  0  5    
4  1  4  17
5  0  4    
6  0  2    
7  0  4    
8  1  4  14
```

---

```
df['C'] = np.where(a.duplicated(keep='last'), np.nan, df['B'].groupby(a).transform('sum'))
print (df)
   A  B     C
0  1  5   NaN
1  0  2   NaN
2  0  1   NaN
3  0  5   NaN
4  1  4  17.0
5  0  4   NaN
6  0  2   NaN
7  0  4   NaN
8  1  4  14.0
```

Detail:

```
print (a)
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    1.0
3    1.0
4    1.0
5    2.0
6    2.0
7    2.0
8    2.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Really nice one sir

Answer (score 0):

Why not sum the columns multiplied by each other:

Iterate a for loop through your table, and when `A==1`, it will add `1*B` to the sum, and when `A==0`, it will add `0*B` to the sum.

Then if you need to get the sum of samples where `A==0`, you iterate the product `(1-A)*B`, so that the process in the sentence above is inverted.

Comment: Thanks, although this will work, the whole idea of using something like pandas is to use vectorised operations and avoid writing for loops. As a matter of fact, I did use this method to get the answer in the meantime. But the above answer by `jezrael` would be the more generalised approach.