# How to count rows between two values of a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column that looks like this:

| flag |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 0 |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 1 |
| 1 |

I want to count/sum the number of rows between two 0s resulting in the following:

| flag | Count |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 0 | 1 |
| 0 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |
| 1 | 4 |

How do I get this? I have tried a solution mentioned in [Pandas - Sum values in one column in between values in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47135016/pandas-sum-values-in-one-column-in-between-values-in-another) This very similar to what I need, but I was not able to modify it to suit my output.

Comment: please post copy-pastable code to generate this data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html#pandas-series-cumsum) to create groups where the flag is 0. Then [groupby tranform](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html#pandas-core-groupby-dataframegroupby-transform) size to get the group sizes:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'flag': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 0, 6: 0, 7: 1, 8: 1, 9: 1}
})

# Create Group IDs based on where 0s are
groups = df.flag.eq(0).cumsum()

# Groupby groups and transform each group to the size
df['Count'] = df.groupby(groups)['flag'].transform('size')

print(df)
```

`df`:

```
   flag  Count
0     0      5
1     1      5
2     1      5
3     1      5
4     1      5
5     0      1
6     0      4
7     1      4
8     1      4
9     1      4
```