# How to calculate the number of rows between two different values in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to calculate how many times a person wakes up during their sleep, and I think the most straight forward method for the data I'm working with is to count the amount of rows between rows containing the tags "Sleep" and "Wake up"

[Picture of the dataframe][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/69SCo.png

I apologize for the imgur link, I am not allowed to post pictures before I hit reputation level 10. The picture probably is not necessary.

I found this thread, but it only works when trying to count the amount of rows between two rows with the same values.

[How to count rows between two values of a pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67602964/how-to-count-rows-between-two-values-of-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: [mre]- you can create a demo dataframe and code it ... nobody hinders you pasting your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it following way, let say you want to get total count of records between START and STOP in following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"action":["A","B","C","START","D","E","STOP","G","START","H","STOP","I"]})
```

then you might do

```
total = 0
inside = False
for i in df["action"]:
    if i=="START":
        inside = True
    elif i=="STOP":
        inside = False
    elif inside:
        total += 1
print(total)  # 3
```

Explanation: simple for loop which does at most one of actions based on current element:

- for START set inside to True
- for STOP set inside to False
- if inside
  increase total